# Could not find endpoint with key StorageEP3. Could not verify Endpoint ready to send status

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I am using WSO2 **API Manager 4.0.0**
and **Micro Integrator 7.0.0**

1- I have a **Load-balance Endpoint** to wsdl endpoints as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="StorageLB" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <loadbalance algorithm="org.apache.synapse.endpoints.algorithms.RoundRobin">
        <endpoint key="StorageEP1"/>
        <endpoint key="StorageEP2"/>
        <endpoint key="StorageEP3"/>
        <endpoint key="StorageEP4"/>
        <endpoint key="StorageEP5"/>
        <endpoint key="StorageEP6"/>
    </loadbalance>
    <description/>
</endpoint>
```

2- My **WSDL Endpoints** are as follows (they are all similar but difference is in server name and port):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="StorageEP1" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <wsdl port="FNCEWS40MTOMPort" service="FNCEWS40Service" uri="http://mystorgeserver:9080/wsi/FNCEWS40MTOM?wsdl">
        <suspendOnFailure>
            <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
            <initialDuration>0</initialDuration>
            <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
            <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
        </suspendOnFailure>
        <markForSuspension>
            <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
        </markForSuspension>
    </wsdl>
</endpoint>
```

Everything was working fine but after uploading new car file I get the following error for all the wsdl endpoints when the user tries to call the API:

```
Could not find endpoint with key StorageEP3. Could not verify Endpoint ready to send status
```

But when trying to get list of endpoints as follows:

```
curl -X GET "https://localhost:9164/management/endpoints" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" -k -i
```

I can see that all the endpoints are active as follows:

```
{
        "name": "StorageEP4",
        "type": "wsdl",
        "isActive": true
    },
    {
        "name": "StorageEP3",
        "type": "wsdl",
        "isActive": true
    }
```

EDIT: Result of this strange behavior is that the API response comes incomplete as follows:

```
{
    "fileName": "test.png",
    "fileSize":12345 ,
    "mimeType": "",
    "dataBase64": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAARMAAAC3CAMAAAAGjUrGAAABC1BMVEX////8GSL8GSD///38Dxz7STXiEBjvFB37Kin7uqX/+Pj8ABP8tqH7ODL+9PLUDRSRAAC4AAD+49uYAACLAAC2CBH/7ev14ODGDRb7wa/"
}
```

or sometimes comes incomplete as follows:

```
{
        "fileName": "",
        "fileSize":,
        "mimeType": "image/png",
        "dataBase64": ""
}
```

**EDIT**: When restarting the micro integrator, it starts fine with no issues as below:

```
[2023-05-18 10:45:47,856]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.deployers.EndpointDeployer} - Endpoint named 'StorageEP2' has been deployed from file : C:\wso2mi-4.1.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1684395947241StorageIntegrationCompositeExporter_1.0.0.car\StorageEP2_1\StorageEP2-1.xml
[2023-05-18 10:45:47,937]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.deployers.EndpointDeployer} - Endpoint named 'StorageEP1' has been deployed from file : C:\wso2mi-4.1.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1684395947241StorageIntegrationCompositeExporter_1.0.0.car\StorageEP1_1\StorageEP1-1.xml
[2023-05-18 10:45:47,952]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.deployers.EndpointDeployer} - Endpoint named 'StorageLB' has been deployed from file : C:\wso2mi-4.1.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1684395947241StorageIntegrationCompositeExporter_1.0.0.car\StorageLB_1\StorageLB-1.xml
[2023-05-18 10:45:48,010]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.deployers.EndpointDeployer} - Endpoint named 'StorageEP4' has been deployed from file : C:\wso2mi-4.1.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1684395947241StorageIntegrationCompositeExporter_1.0.0.car\StorageEP4_1\StorageEP4-1.xml
[2023-05-18 10:45:48,074]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.deployers.EndpointDeployer} - Endpoint named 'StorageEP3' has been deployed from file : C:\wso2mi-4.1.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1684395947241StorageIntegrationCompositeExporter_1.0.0.car\StorageEP3_1\StorageEP3-1.xml
[2023-05-18 10:45:48,128]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.deployers.EndpointDeployer} - Endpoint named 'StorageEP6' has been deployed from file : C:\wso2mi-4.1.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1684395947241StorageIntegrationCompositeExporter_1.0.0.car\StorageEP6_1\StorageEP6-1.xml
[2023-05-18 10:45:48,186]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.deployers.EndpointDeployer} - Endpoint named 'StorageEP5' has been deployed from file : C:\wso2mi-4.1.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1684395947241StorageIntegrationCompositeExporter_1.0.0.car\StorageEP5_1\StorageEP5-1.xml
[2023-05-18 10:45:48,246]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.deployers.EndpointDeployer} - Endpoint named 'StorageNewEP2' has been deployed from file : C:\wso2mi-4.1.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1684395947241StorageIntegrationCompositeExporter_1.0.0.car\StorageNewEP2_1\StorageNewEP2-1.xml
[2023-05-18 10:45:48,304]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.deployers.EndpointDeployer} - Endpoint named 'StorageNewEP1' has been deployed from file : C:\wso2mi-4.1.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1684395947241StorageIntegrationCompositeExporter_1.0.0.car\StorageNewEP1_1\StorageNewEP1-1.xml
[2023-05-18 10:45:48,312]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.deployers.EndpointDeployer} - Endpoint named 'StorageNewLB' has been deployed from file : C:\wso2mi-4.1.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1684395947241StorageIntegrationCompositeExporter_1.0.0.car\StorageNewLB_1\StorageNewLB-1.xml
[2023-05-18 10:45:48,574]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment} - Continuation call is set to true
[2023-05-18 10:45:48,578]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.deployers.SequenceDeployer} - Sequence named 'StorageGetMimeTypeSeq' has been deployed from file : C:\wso2mi-4.1.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1684395947241StorageIntegrationCompositeExporter_1.0.0.car\StorageGetMimeTypeSeq_1\StorageGetMimeTypeSeq-1.xml
[2023-05-18 10:45:48,598]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.deployers.SequenceDeployer} - Sequence named 'StorageAPIFaultSeq' has been deployed from file : C:\wso2mi-4.1.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1684395947241StorageIntegrationCompositeExporter_1.0.0.car\StorageAPIFaultSeq_1\StorageAPIFaultSeq-1.xml
[2023-05-18 10:45:48,713]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.deployers.SequenceDeployer} - Sequence named 'StorageGetDocumentSeq' has been deployed from file : C:\wso2mi-4.1.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1684395947241StorageIntegrationCompositeExporter_1.0.0.car\StorageGetDocumentSeq_1\StorageGetDocumentSeq-1.xml
[2023-05-18 10:45:48,830]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.deployers.SequenceDeployer} - Sequence named 'StorageSaveDocumentSeq' has been deployed from file : C:\wso2mi-4.1.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1684395947241StorageIntegrationCompositeExporter_1.0.0.car\StorageSaveDocumentSeq_1\StorageSaveDocumentSeq-1.xml
[2023-05-18 10:45:48,898]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.deployers.SequenceDeployer} - Sequence named 'StorageDeleteDocumentSeq' has been deployed from file : C:\wso2mi-4.1.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1684395947241StorageIntegrationCompositeExporter_1.0.0.car\StorageDeleteDocumentSeq_1\StorageDeleteDocumentSeq-1.xml
[2023-05-18 10:45:48,928]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.deployers.SequenceDeployer} - Sequence named 'StorageSaveDocumentValidatorSeq' has been deployed from file : C:\wso2mi-4.1.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1684395947241StorageIntegrationCompositeExporter_1.0.0.car\StorageSaveDocumentValidatorSeq_1\StorageSaveDocumentValidatorSeq-1.xml
[2023-05-18 10:45:48,943]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.deployers.SequenceDeployer} - Sequence named 'StorageRequestValidatorSeq' has been deployed from file : C:\wso2mi-4.1.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1684395947241StorageIntegrationCompositeExporter_1.0.0.car\StorageRequestValidatorSeq_1\StorageRequestValidatorSeq-1.xml
[2023-05-18 10:45:48,958]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.deployers.TemplateDeployer} - Template named 'StorageEndpointTemplate' has been deployed from file : C:\wso2mi-4.1.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1684395947241StorageIntegrationCompositeExporter_1.0.0.car\StorageEndpointTemplate_1\StorageEndpointTemplate-1.xml
[2023-05-18 10:45:49,027]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.api.API} - {api:StorageAPI} Initializing API: StorageAPI
[2023-05-18 10:45:49,031]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.deployers.APIDeployer} - API named 'StorageAPI' has been deployed from file : C:\wso2mi-4.1.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1684395947241StorageIntegrationCompositeExporter_1.0.0.car\StorageAPI_1\StorageAPI-1.xml
[2023-05-18 10:45:49,031]  INFO {org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.application.deployer.CappDeployer} - Successfully Deployed Carbon Application : StorageIntegrationCompositeExporter_1.0.0{super-tenant}
[2023-05-18 10:45:49,098]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.core.PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through HTTP Listener started on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8290
[2023-05-18 10:45:49,161]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.core.PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through HTTPS Listener started on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8253
[2023-05-18 10:45:49,162]  INFO {org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.StartupFinalizer} - WSO2 Micro Integrator started in 9.88 seconds
[2023-05-18 10:45:49,308]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.core.PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through EI_INTERNAL_HTTP_INBOUND_ENDPOINT Listener started on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9201
[2023-05-18 10:45:49,410]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.core.PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through EI_INTERNAL_HTTPS_INBOUND_ENDPOINT Listener started on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9164
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is generated from [here](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/1bf5f1247131c74045afd7e4ef32bfc143f9948d/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/endpoints/IndirectEndpoint.java#L86) and the ready state is checked by [this](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/1bf5f1247131c74045afd7e4ef32bfc143f9948d/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/endpoints/EndpointContext.java#L424) method. So probably the endpoint is somehow in a suspended state. Probably a restrat to MI will resolve the issue. You can find the exact cause by enabling debug logs to the package `org.apache.synapse.endpoints` in `log4j2.properties`.

**Update**

Just realized the error is logged after a Exception is thrown, hence the state might not be the reason. Somewhere in [this method](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/1bf5f1247131c74045afd7e4ef32bfc143f9948d/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/endpoints/EndpointContext.java#L424), a NulPointer is thrown.

Comment: I restarted the MI and the issue is the same. 
how to make the endpoint never suspend in the first place, please see my above configuration for the endpoint StorageEP1

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh Your endpoint suspension configs looks good, So ideally the endpoints shouldn't get suspended. Something else is going on. Do you see an error trace? If so we can know from where the NullPointer is thrown. Also can you enable debug logs.

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh Also since you are only getting this with the new Car file, Try doing this as well. Stop the MI server, delete <MI_HOME>/tmp directory, and then start the server.

Comment: I deleted tmp then restarted with same issue, the only change I made in this new car file is that I changed the endpoint uri from IP to DNS name (DNS name is for the old ip)

Comment: please see my edit in the post above, I added some more logs

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh please enable debug logs and share the logs.